# O que possivelmente este código está fazendo?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, e-commerce

**index.xhtml** :

```
 ui:repeat value="#{produtoService.listaProdutos}" var="prod"
```

Obs: eu sei que falta fechar as tags. Mas ou seja, o que este código está  fazendo (''supondo'' que as tags estão fechadas corretamente)?

Answer (score 0):

`ui:repeat` é uma forma de laço `while`, mais especificamente `foreach`.

Nesse seu exemplo específico, pode ser interpretado como: Para cada item de `listaProdutos`, coloque o item atual na variável `prod` e execute o código até o `</ui:repeat>`